# In AWS, can I create a custom event for Cloudwatch to signal Autoscale to scale EC2's?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

To AWS Devs,
I want to scale EC2's based on a custom metric and what appears to be a convoluted way to do this is through Cloudwatch and Autoscale.  An app would create a custom metric to Cloudwatch and based on a rule, signal to Autoscale to scale the EC2's.  First, is this possible and second it is not an anti-pattern?
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Yes, this is a common pattern, using custom metrics like queue length or request latency to scale a cluster. There are a number of examples on the web. I'm not sure why you think this is convoluted.

Comment: @jarmod actually the two specific examples you listed are bad candidates. Look for "The following metrics do not work:" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html

Comment: @Kashyap thanks, that's a very useful document. I was hoping to share the fact that Auto Scaling on custom metrics was a supported, and common, practice as a general rule but that document does provide some very specific details of what types of metrics do not work for target tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes. [Target tracking scaling policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html) seems to be the one you want.

> Is it an anti pattern?

IMO no. If you have a piece of code that's monitoring and changing value of targeted metric, then maaay be yes. 
What you want is to choose a metric reported by every instance in your auto scaling group, and create the policy on it's aggregated value. Not the value of a metric reported only by your monitoring job/code.